# Excel VBA Worksheet_Change Problem Not Calculating

Tags: excel, vba

I apologise if this is a simple question but I can't seem to work it out.

I have a spreadsheet which has cells returning values from external links. I then have cells/formulas pointing to this data running calculations. What I need to happen is to "log" (write cells values) to other cells when certain criteria are met, so I can go back and review the raw data that was there at the time. I have a cell (P3) using an IF function to return "1" when all criteria are met (i.e. when 1 appears in P3 I need the cell values copied).

This is as far as I have got:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
      If Range("P3").Value = 1 Then
      Range("AL9").Value = Range("AJ9").Value
      Range("AL11").Value = Range("AJ11").Value
      Range("AL13").Value = Range("AJ13").Value
      Range("AL15").Value = Range("AJ15").Value
      Range("AL17").Value = Range("AJ17").Value
      Range("AL19").Value = Range("AJ19").Value
      Range("AL21").Value = Range("AJ21").Value
      Range("AL23").Value = Range("AJ23").Value
      End If

End Sub
```

I originally tried with Worksheet_Change but it only works when P3 is manually updated, and doesn't work when using a formula.

When testing in the sheet with the external data, once 1 appears in P3, all formula cells stop calculating... almost like the sheet is half frozen. The external data cells still update as per usual.

Can anyone please point me in the right direction.

Thanks

Comment: I suspect your sheets calculation options are not set to `Automatic`. Can you verify if they are? (Go to Formulas Tab > Calculation Options)

Comment: Hi Sam, Thanks for your reply. It is definitely set on Automatic.

Comment: I'd like to also ask - Is there a way I can set this Worksheet_Calculate macro function to only run when P3 changes, instead of any changes on the entire worksheet? When I researched online I couldn't find anything to assist. THanks

Comment: I don't think you can force the `Worksheet_Calculate` event to only fire in certain circumstances... however you could use the `Worksheet_Change` event which is evaluated whenever anything changes on the sheet - by default it has a `Target` parameter which you would write code to calculate the sheet if the changed cell is your desired target - e.g. `If Target.Address = "$P$3" Then...Do Something` or `If Target = <YourSheetReference>.Range("P3") Then...Do something`. [See the Worksheet.Change event here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.change)

Comment: Thanks Sam - The problem with Worksheet_Change is it only works when the cell is manually changed (i.e. click in the cell and manually type "1"). A formula changing does not trigger it. So I believe Worksheet_Calculate is my only option. Going back to the original problem - Can you see any reason why when "1" appears, the macro does not work and my formulas stop calculating? Is there a better way of achieving what I want to do? Thank you.

Comment: I think your explanation is a little unclear so I'm going to try specify some things. 
When you say *my macro does not work* is it throwing an error or just not running the code? 
When you say *my formulas stop calculating* do you mean sheet values are not updating as expected per the formulas in certain cells? 
I've just tested your above code logic which works fine. When stepping through the code, regardless of if the cell `P3` value was set to 1 by typing it in, setting `=J4` in the cell and typing 1 into `J4` or using an `IF` statement to set 1 to the cell, the code was running.

Comment: OK - When I had the external data coming in, when the macro triggered it appeared the macro did nothing, and all formulas stopped calculating/updating. There was no error. I've now gone and recreated a simple example to test further. What I have found is - as I need to reference these copied cells in further calculations, when I have put references in, it throws an error "Run-time error, Method 'value' of object 'Range' failed. If I remove these references, it works fine.

Comment: Please see here - https://drive.google.com/file/d/1h_KjbgIvEyAZAaS0ttUC6tthkfEuhgu4/view?usp=sharing - If you type "Yes" into L3 to trigger P3, you receive the error. If you remove the references in H:H, it all works fine... So my new question is - How can I reference the newly copied cells in AL:AL?

Comment: I've found the issue, will post an answer in a moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking at your example workbook I set a code break on the `If` statement line.

I updated the indicated cell (`L3`) to 'Yes' as instructed which populated the formula cell (`P3`) with 1 and triggered the `Worksheet_Calculate` event.

And there lies your problem, your code was triggering the `Worksheet_Calculate` event after the first line in the `If` block was executed, which resulted in an endless loop never getting past the line `Range("AL10").Value = Range("AJ10").Value`.

A solution to this is encapsulating the `If` block statements within a call to disable/enable `Application.EnableEvents`, which is what allows or disallows the `Worksheet_Calculate` event to be called.

This will fix your issue:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()

If Me.Range("P3").Value = 1 Then
    Application.EnableEvents = False    'Disallow calls to the Worksheet_Calculate event (among other things...)
    Range("AL10").Value = Range("AJ10").Value
    Range("AL12").Value = Range("AJ12").Value
    Range("AL14").Value = Range("AJ14").Value
    Range("AL16").Value = Range("AJ16").Value
    Range("AL18").Value = Range("AJ18").Value
    Range("AL20").Value = Range("AJ20").Value
    Range("AL22").Value = Range("AJ22").Value
    Range("AL24").Value = Range("AJ24").Value
    Application.EnableEvents = True    'Allow calls to the Worksheet_Calculate event (among other things...)
End If
End Sub
```

It's important to understand what the `Application.EnableEvents` property affects. You can read about it [here in the MS documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.enableevents).

Comment: Genius - Thank you!